# What's the advantage of manually registering resource classes in JAX-RS application?

Tags: java, resources, jax-rs, registration, multiple-inclusions

[Excerpt from JEE 7 tutorial:](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm)

> 29.2.7.1 Configuring a JAX-RS Application Using a Subclass of Application
>
> ...
>
> By default, all the resources in an archive will be processed for
>   resources. Override the getClasses method to manually register the
>   resource classes in the application with the JAX-RS runtime.

Questions:

1. When by default, all resources in an archive will be processed, what's the advantage of registering resources manually?
2. As I understand, #1 helps to exclude resources(correct me if wrong). If I want to exclude a resource, I would just comment `@Path` on a resource. In either case(manual registration and commenting), the source code needs to be touched.
3. Isn't it better to have exclusion feature as deployment descriptor entry? Is there such an option?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, to gain more control (security) you need an **inclusive approach** which will prevent adding classes  **implicitly**

Notice you can also add manually filters (`ContainerRequestFilter`) for specific resources